# Guardian Shield: Does it stack?

Tags: starcraft-2

Protoss [sentry](http://sc2armory.com/game/protoss/units/sentry) units have the Guardian Shield ability which:

> Creates a range 4 aura that reduces incoming ranged damage to
>   friendly units by 2. Lasts 15 seconds.

If a unit is sitting inside the guardian shield created by **TWO** different sentries, is the overall damage reduction still just 2, or is the damage stacking and first reduced by 2 for sentry shield 1, and then another 2 for sentry shield 2, for a total of 4 damaged mitigated?

Comment: I don't think it does, but can't say for sure so no answer :).

Comment: Note that if it did stack, it would be relatively easy to make an army that was impervious to ranged attacks, which would be rather imbalanced.

Comment: Agreed, that is why I was pretty certain there was no stacking, but in case there were imposed limits on the stacking, etc, I thought I would check.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it does not stack.  The unit is either protected by Guardian Shield or it is not.  It will still only prevent 2 damage.

Comment: This fact isn't necessarily a reason to cast Guardian Shield only once. Good players will often snipe the casting Sentry and this places an unnecessary burden on your APM. If they have to attack multiple Sentries they're less likely to focus fire them.

Comment: Also 1 Sentry isn't always enough to cover all your forces, if you have a concave then you do have to do more then 1.